# Mysqldump produces strange char, why 【国家】 becomes 【鍥藉】in dumped .sql file？

Tags: mysql

mysql 5.6.26 on windows server, dumped with `mysqldump -uxx -p123 db > db.sql`

`SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set%';`:

```
character_set_client    utf8
character_set_connection    utf8
character_set_database  utf8
character_set_filesystem    binary
character_set_results   utf8
```

Sql file is opened with Notepad++, encoding UTF-16 BE BOM

`file db.sql`:

`Little-endian UTF-16 Unicode text, with very long lines, with CRLF line terminators`

run `show create table dim_area;`

```
CREATE TABLE `dim_area` (
  `area` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'area',
  `area_id` int(20) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'area_id',
  `country` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '国家',
  `province` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '省份',
  `city` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '城市',
  `county` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '县'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci COMMENT='dim_area[地区表]'
```

same table in dumped file:

```
CREATE TABLE `dim_area` (
  `area` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'area',
  `area_id` int(20) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'area_id',
  `country` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '鍥藉',
  `province` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '鐪佷唤',
  `city` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '鍩庡競',
  `county` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '鍘?
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci COMMENT='dim_area[鍦板尯琛╙';
```

very strange

Comment: Mysql **5.6.51** was end of life 28 Feb 2021, two years ago  (see: https://endoflife.date/mysql ). Some of these problems might have been solved. (see: [Release Notes 5.7](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.7/en/) and [Release Notes 8.0](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/8.0/en/)).   Would it not be a great time to upgrade?

Comment: yes, I'm dumping sql file and move them to a much up-to-date mysql

Comment: I guess you are, only a bit,  too late.  May I which you succes on the upgrade process?  Because this is probably not the only _problem_ you need to solve.

Comment: P.S. Maybe someone at https://dba.stackexchange.com/ has more insights........ (Before this question is closed because of 'not-reproduccable', or 'off-topic' 

Comment: Okay. I'm trying to dump it with navicat

Answer (score 0):

I tried to repeat the steps using 5.6.51, this seems all OK:

Change code page of terminal window:

```
D:\TEMP>chcp 65001
Active code page: 65001
```

I created the table using:

```
CREATE TABLE `dim_area` (
  `area` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'area',
  `area_id` int(20) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'area_id',
  `country` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '国家',
  `province` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '省份',
  `city` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '城市',
  `county` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '县'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci COMMENT='dim_area[地区表]'
```

and then dumped it:

```
D:\TEMP>D:\mysql-5.6.51-winx64\bin\mysqldump.exe -u root -p -P 3386 test dim_area
Enter password:
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.6.51, for Win64 (x86_64)
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: test
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version       5.6.51

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;

--
-- Table structure for table `dim_area`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `dim_area`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `dim_area` (
  `area` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'area',
  `area_id` int(20) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'area_id',
  `country` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '国家',
  `province` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '省份',
  `city` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '城市',
  `county` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '县'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci COMMENT='dim_area[地区表]';
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `dim_area`
--

LOCK TABLES `dim_area` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `dim_area` DISABLE KEYS */;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `dim_area` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE */;

/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
/*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;

-- Dump completed on 2023-05-14 16:37:16
```

NOTE: The encoding of the command prompt might not be correct. That's why I changed it using `chcp 65001`

P.S. My temporary 5.6.51 server is running on port 3386, when it is started, and does not have a password

Comment: thanks, The only difference is version of db. The chcp 65001 command doesn't make difference

Comment: Which characters are having trouble?  What is the HEX of those characters?